# Making Json request to php mysql through android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I wanted to search from mysql from android using json request, Google provide this code but i am getting this problem in this code, i don't know where  i getting wrong....

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Here is my main activity..

```
public class JSONUseActivity extends Activity {

    EditText byear;   // To take birthyear as input from user
    Button submit;    
    TextView tv;      // TextView to show the result of MySQL query 

     String returnString;   // to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build()); 
        // StrictMode is most commonly used to
                                                                        // catch
                                                                        // accidental
                                                                        // disk
                                                                        // or
                                                                        // network
                                                                        // access
                                                                        // on
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // application's
                                                                        // main
                                                                        // thread

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsonuse);

        byear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);

     // define the action when user clicks on submit button
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){        
         public void onClick(View v) {
          // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the name "birthyear" and its value submitted by user   
          ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

          // define the parameter
          postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birthyear",byear.getText().toString()));
          String response = null;

          // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
          try {
              response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/jsonscript.php",postParameters);

  // store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
     String result = response.toString();   

      //parse json data
         try{
                 returnString = "";

                 JSONObject mainObject=new JSONObject();
                // JSONArray dataArray=new JSONArray();

                 //dataArray=mainObject.getJSONArray("Table");

                 //JSONArray jArray = mainObject.getJSONArray(result);
                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                     Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                             ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                             ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                             ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear") );
                     //Get an output to the screen                        
                     returnString += "\n" + json_data.getString("name").toString() + " -> "+ json_data.getString("birthyear").toString();
                     }
                 }
         catch(JSONException e){
             Log.e("Json_log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
             }
         try{
             tv.setText(returnString);
             }
         catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());
             }   
         }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());
              }
          }
         }); 
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.jsonuse, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and second activity.

```
public class CustomHttpClient {


    /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */

     public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds


     /** Single instance of our HttpClient */

     private static HttpClient mHttpClient;


     /**

      * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.

      * 

      * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set

      */

     private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
         if (mHttpClient == null) {
             mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
             HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
             HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
             ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
             }
         return mHttpClient;
         }


     /**

      * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the specified

      * parameters.

      * 

      * @param url

      *            The web address to post the request to

      * @param postParameters

      *            The parameters to send via the request

      * @return The result of the request

      * @throws Exception

      */

     public static String executeHttpPost(String url,ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
         BufferedReader in = null;
         try {

             HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
             HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

             UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
             request.setEntity(formEntity);

             HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

             in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

             StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
             String line = "";
             String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {               
                 sb.append(line + NL);
                 }

             in.close();             
             String result = sb.toString();

             return result;

             } finally {
                 if (in != null) {
                     try {
                         in.close();
                         } catch (IOException e) {
                             Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                             e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                     }
                 }
         }


     /**

      * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.

      * 

      * @param url

      *            The web address to post the request to

      * @return The result of the request

      * @throws Exception

      */

     public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {

      BufferedReader in = null;

      try {
          HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
          HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
          request.setURI(new URI(url));
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
          String line = "";
          String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(line + NL);
              }
          in.close();
          String result = sb.toString();
          return result;
          } finally {
              if (in != null) {
                  try {
                      in.close();
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                          e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                  }
              }
      }
     }
```

Please point me, where i am getting wrong code..

Comment: The data you're trying to parse is not JSON but XML. Make sure the server you're hitting with the request returns JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse me for my English...
 I am not sure what is the Problem.. but i can suggest you that

```
String result = response.toString();
```

Here you are taking result as String but

```
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

but here you are passing String to JSONArray. that is causing the error...

try like this

```
String  responseBodyFH = EntityUtils.toString((HttpEntity) response);
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseBodyFH);
    String status = jObj.getString("status");
    String code = jObj.getString("code");
```

try to use like this here status and code is returning from web services.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.104/phpweb/phpresponse.php");
            HttpResponse httpResponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //  content=EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            HttpEntity httpentity=httpResponse.getEntity();
            is=httpentity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
                singlecolumn.add(line);


            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString(); 
            System.out.println("=========result"+result);




            JSONArray json=new JSONArray(result);
              JSONObject jo = null;

              list1=new String[json.length()];
              list2=new String[json.length()];

            for(int i=0; i<json.length(); i++) {

                jo = json.getJSONObject(i);
                list1[i] = jo.getString("studentname");
                list2[i] =  jo.getString("sno");

            System.out.println("######"+list1[i]);



            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: code is not working. any easy way to request to localhost using post method.

Answer (score 0):

```
simple way to get http response from server

  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.codeincloud.tk/First.php");
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

if you have any doubts follow
http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-php-web-service-client.html
sampleprogramz.com